# Jquery ScrollTo - Center on Div

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a mid section div on my site and an animation that moves a background image down the page when clicked.

What I would like to do is to scroll that image, or specify the page to centre vertically on that div.

I have tried the below, but no dice.

```
$.scrollTo( '.midsection', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );
```

Comment: Where did you get the `elasout` easing formula?

Comment: Just a random snippet. It's not required.

Comment: Could you post a bit more code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It works fine, just wasn't in the HTML `<body>` section.

```
$.scrollTo( { top:1000, left:0}, 800 );
```